# rake db:migrate is not working and giving an error in terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rake, dbmigrate, bcrypt-ruby

So im trying to run rake db:migrate and i get this error in the terminal?

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext  
C:/Users/Josh/loveapp/app/models/user.rb:4:in `<class:User>'
C:/Users/Josh/loveapp/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Users/Josh/loveapp/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/Users/Josh/loveapp/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:-1:in `execute_if_updated'
C:/Users/Josh/loveapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- 2.2/bcrypt_ext
C:/Users/Josh/loveapp/app/models/user.rb:4:in `<class:User>'
C:/Users/Josh/loveapp/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Users/Josh/loveapp/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/Users/Josh/loveapp/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:-1:in `execute_if_updated'
C:/Users/Josh/loveapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I recently added bcrypt to my gemfile because i tried running "rails destroy devise user" and it gave me an error about bcrypt and then i went to stack overflow, someone said to add that to your gemfile. But instead of the specific version it gave me , (was an outdated gem file) i just added this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.3'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record


# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.1.0.rc2'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end
group :doc do

  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Comment: [BCrypt GitHub](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby)

Try removing it from the Gemfile and in the terminal writing `gem install bcrypt` as per the README

Comment: please try `gem 'bcrypt-ruby', :require => 'bcrypt'` and `bundle install`

Comment: none of this is working? @chanakyadevraj

Answer (score 0):

run `bundle install` to install bcrypt from terminal and rerun `bundle exec rake db:migrate`